# clingo return the max subset

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I have the following code:

```
1{p(1..10)}10.
:- p(I*2).
```

and it shows 31 answers, But I just need the max subset `p(1) p(3) p(5) p(7) p(9).`
How can I do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for an optimization. Easiest fix would be adding

```
#maximize{I:p(I)}.
```

resulting in

```
Solving...
Answer: 1
p(9)
Optimization: -9
Answer: 2
p(5) p(9)
Optimization: -14
Answer: 3
p(7) p(9)
Optimization: -16
Answer: 4
p(5) p(7) p(9)
Optimization: -21
Answer: 5
p(1) p(5) p(7) p(9)
Optimization: -22
Answer: 6
p(3) p(5) p(7) p(9)
Optimization: -24
Answer: 7
p(1) p(3) p(5) p(7) p(9)
Optimization: -25
OPTIMUM FOUND
```

Don't worry about the negative score, clingo converts `#maximize` into `#minimize`, therefore the negation. So what does `#maximize{I:p(I)}.` do?  In general you want to maximize over `I` for all `p(I)`, which in this case is the sum of `I`. Just counting would be

```
#maximize{1,I:p(I)}.
```

resulting in

```
Answer: 1
p(9)
Optimization: -1
Answer: 2
p(5) p(9)
Optimization: -2
Answer: 3
p(5) p(7) p(9)
Optimization: -3
Answer: 4
p(3) p(5) p(7) p(9)
Optimization: -4
Answer: 5
p(1) p(3) p(5) p(7) p(9)
Optimization: -5
OPTIMUM FOUND
```